# How to log out of the account on all devices currently logged in using Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-8

I'm using `logoutOtherDevices`. I don't know how to log out of the account on all devices currently logged in using Laravel. I am using Laravel Framework 8.83.27.

I have tried using it this way, and it doesn't log out even though I have used an incognito tab

```
\Auth::guard('admin')->logoutOtherDevices($requests->password);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that you incognito and non-incognito sessions are using a different cookie? Have you explored the library code in `logoutOtherDevices()` to see if it has a reasonable chance of doing what you expect?

Comment: Are you testing this locally, so you can add temporary logging to library code?

Comment: my config guards 
'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin_users',
        ],
    ],

Comment: my route 
->name('admin.')->prefix(config('app.admin_dir'))->middleware(['web', 'auth-admin', '2fa'])->group(function()

Comment: public function changePasswordPost(Request $requests, $id) {
       ...
        extract($requests->all(), EXTR_OVERWRITE);
        $password = $this->passwordHandle($requests);
        $compact = compact('password');
        // Cập nhật tại database
        $this->models->updateRecord($requests, $id, $compact, $this->has_seo, false);
        \Auth::guard('admin')->user()->refresh();
            \Auth::guard('admin')->logoutOtherDevices($requests->password);
    }

Comment: But it doesn't work

Comment: ^ Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77701474/edit) with any additional information. You can add an **Update** section at the end.